# How to add notes ABOVE a table in latex?

Tags: tables, notes

I need to write a paper with the style of Jounal of Finance. I am having problems when trying to create a table with notes at the beggining. Here I attach a picture of how the table should look like:

[image]

I hope you could help me with the code. Thanks

Code:

```
\begin{table}[h!] 
\centering 
\begin{threeparttable} 
\caption{} \label{Table1}{\textbf{Descriptive Statistics for the Industry. 2007 - 2017}} 
\begin{tablenotes} 
\small 
\item Text here 
\end{tablenotes} 
\begin{tabular}{lcccc} 
.... 
\end{tabular} 
\end{threeparttable} 
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a minimal compilable example code?

Comment: Where is the problem? Simply type the text below the caption.

Comment: Hi, I am doing the following: \begin{table}[h!]
\centering
 \begin{threeparttable}
\caption{}
\label{Table1}{\textbf{Descriptive Statistics for the Industry. 2007 - 2017}}

\begin{tablenotes}
      \small
      \item Text here

    \end{tablenotes}
    
  \begin{tabular}{lcccc} 
....
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

However is not aligned as in the picture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `threeparttable` is messing you up. Remove it and just write under the label or under the caption, whichever it is you prefer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
%\usepackage{threeparttable}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!] 
\centering 
\caption{Sample ANOVA table}
write here option 1 \\
\label{Table1}{\textbf{Descriptive Statistics for the Industry. 2007 - 2017}} \\
write here option 2 \\
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
        \toprule
        Stubhead & \( df \) & \( f \) & \( \eta \) & \( p \) \\
        \midrule
                 &     \multicolumn{4}{c}{Spanning text}     \\
        Row 1    & 1        & 0.67    & 0.55       & 0.41    \\
        Row 2    & 2        & 0.02    & 0.01       & 0.39    \\
        Row 3    & 3        & 0.15    & 0.33       & 0.34    \\
        Row 4    & 4        & 1.00    & 0.76       & 0.54    \\
        \bottomrule
     \end{tabular}  
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. However, the text that goes in say in your example "write here option 2" now is centered and I would like it to be justified as in my picture. Could you also help me with this?

Thank you!

Comment: @chora move the \centering down behind the text.

Comment: but I want the label part (Descriptive Statistics for the Industry..) to be centered, if I do this the label part is not centered anymore..

Comment: @chora post as a new question please

Answer (score 4):

[image]

How does this work for you?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
%\usepackage{threeparttable}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!] 
\centering 
\caption{Sample ANOVA table}
write here option 1 \\
\label{Table1}{\textbf{Descriptive Statistics for the Industry. 2007 - 2017}} \\
write here option 2 \\
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
\multicolumn{5}{@{}p{3in}@{}}{Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. } \\ 
\toprule
Stubhead & \( df \) & \( f \) & \( \eta \) & \( p \) \\
\midrule
&     \multicolumn{4}{c}{Spanning text}     \\
Row 1    & 1        & 0.67    & 0.55       & 0.41    \\
Row 2    & 2        & 0.02    & 0.01       & 0.39    \\
Row 3    & 3        & 0.15    & 0.33       & 0.34    \\
Row 4    & 4        & 1.00    & 0.76       & 0.54    \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}  
\end{table}

\end{document}
```